# Slider component with more than one row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create the slider. Now I have something like this :

[image]

Everything is in one row, but I want to have something like :

[image]

Thus I want to be able to set more than one row in the slider.

**UPDATE**

This is a [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50081/)

Comment: then you can append another **innerDiv**, right?

Comment: I try to do it dynamically.

Comment: Dynamically means how? Like appending a row on a button click or what?. And how many div should be there in the innerDiv element?

Comment: Since you made it a component, why don't you use two sliders? Is the data source the same?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<div class="row"></div>` with style

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

So it would be like

```
<div class="outterDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 7</div>
      <div class="item">Item 8</div>
      <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item 10</div>
      <div class="item">Item 11</div>
      <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

updated jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50082

Comment: That is not bad. I thought on something else, but your solution is also nice. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: Update your firts answer with jsfiddle.